# Using DataProvider across different Test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

**Issue:-** Trying to use Data Provider across different test methods. The error message for the below code is:- *The data provider is trying to pass 6 parameters but the method testcases.useDataProvider#Login takes 2*

**Code:-**

```
public class useDataProvider {

@DataProvider (name="dp1")
public Object[][] getData(){
//Code for reading from excel

//Returning 6 Strings
return data;            
}

@Test(dataProvider="dp1")
public void Login(String username, String password) {
System.out.println("The User is:-"+username);
System.out.println("The Password is:-"+password);
}

@Test(dataProvider="dp1", dependsOnMethods = { "Login" })
public void testCase(String q1, String a1, String q2, String a2) {
System.out.println("The Security Q1 is:-"+q1);
System.out.println("The Security A1 is:-"+a1);
System.out.println("The Security Q2 is:-"+q2);
System.out.println("The Security A2 is:-"+a2);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same dataprovider for different tests that take different parameters won't work.  You can reduce code duplication by putting the excel-reading code in the constructor, or do it statically.

Then you can have two different data providers that pass in different types of data.

Comment: Ok, have never used constructors..will try to use those and work with DataProvider & Test annotation. Thanks.